# How to skip some specified sections when exporting .org file?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

There are some parts in my `.org` file that I don't want to be exported. I am not sure how could I do that. Here is an example file to illustrate what I mean:

```
* Should be exported
  bla bla

** Should be exported

*** Secret part that should not be exported; the same goes for its child sections
    The contents should not be exported either.

**** Child section (not exported)

*** Should be exported

** Should be exported
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use export and noexport tags to accomplish it. In order to enable this feature, you need to add

`#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export`

`#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport`

to you document.

Comment: At document level it's `#+SELECT_TAGS` and `#+EXCLUDE_TAGS`; you can prefix them with `EXPORT_` when setting *subtree-specific* export options. @enchanter Note that you don't have to add these lines to your `.org` file - unless you want to use *custom* tags for telling `org-mode` which sections (not) to export. `export` and `noexport` are default values for the `#+SELECT_TAGS` and `#+EXCLUDE_TAGS` settings. See [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) for a full list of export settings that are available to you.

Comment: With emacs 27, and as of April 4th, 2022, in my setup, adding a tag :noexport: at the end of a section header that should prevent the section from being exported.